# Is it possible to pop view controller from navigation controller in iOS while the app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to pop view controller from navigation controller in iOS while the app is in background?
I wrote a background task. When I switch my app to background, some code can still be executed but `vc.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:false)` doesn't have any effect. I'm sure it's executed.

Comment: I doubt this happens as Application is required to be in active state to perform any UI transitions. You can add the task to app lifecycle method either before going to background or coming to foreground to execute this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Transition is only working in main thread I think. 
So, Your pop to root is in background thread. 
This may cause your application crash some time.
I think the only solutions is popToRoot when you're about to let your app go to background. Handle the delegate from Appdelegate to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My solution is to remember useful app state when background task expiration handler is called and then use the remembered state to popToRoot when app becomes active again (received foreground notification).